# How can I make the button stay enabled just when I choice a item of options?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want that my button ' + ', stay enabled, but only when I make a choice in the select.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <button (click)="setItem()">Items</button>
    <select class="custom-select">
      <option *ngFor="let item of itemSelected">
        <a (click)="freeBtn()">{{ item }}</a>
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" [disabled]="isActive">+ 
  </button>
</div>

itemSelected = [];
items = ['Test A', 'Test B', 'Test C', 'Test D', 'Test E'];
isActive = true;

setItem(){
  this.itemSelected = this.items;
  console.log(this.itemSelected);
}

freeBtn(){
  this.isActive = false;
}
```

The problem is that the `<a (click)="freeBtn()></a>"` does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to hook into the change event of the select, not add a click to every option that won't work for many reasons.

Example:

```
<select (change)="freeBtn($event.target.value)">
<option *ngFor="let item of itemSelected">
 {{ item }}
</option>
</select>
```

So isActive starts out false, when you select something it becomes true and your button is disabled

Comment: After some researches, I found that solution. But, I appreciate your help, thanks!